# PHP Pessoal como listar as array que estão com o limite menor que 30 min

Tags: php

Pessoal comentei no codigo abaixo o que preciso espero que me entendam se alguem puder dar uma forca aqui agradeço

conheço bem pouco de php obrigado !

```html
<?php
// Fazemos o Comando que queremos no Mikrotik
if ($API->connect($ip, $login, $senha)) {
$ARRAY = $API->comm("/ip/hotspot/user/print");
// Preparamos o Loop
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ARRAY); ++$i)
{
$resultado = $ARRAY[$i];
//print_r($ARRAY);
?>



 <?php echo  $resultado['limit-uptime'];?> 

acima  vem as respostas no echo exemplo:
usuario: 30m
usuario menor que 29m 

quero apenas que lista os usuários que que estao com o tempo menor que 30m






<?php } /* Fechamos o While */ ?>
<?php } /* Fechamos o IF */ ?>
```

Comment: `$resultado['limit-uptime']` imprime exatamente isso `usuario: 30m`? Ou apenas o valor?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode tentar assim:

troque `$resultado = $ARRAY[$i];` por:

```
if ($ARRAY[$i]['limit-uptime'] < 30) {

    $resultado = $ARRAY[$i];
}
```

quando você coloca a variável `$resultado` dentro do `if` ela só vai receber os dados se for de acordo com a condição que você colocou no `if`

Comment: Cuidado. Do jeito que está aí, `'30'` é uma string e não um número. Assumindo que `limit-uptime` já seja um número, o correto é fazer: `$ARRAY[$i]['limit-uptime'] < 30`

Comment: Independente. No seu exemplo, você está comparando algo que a gente não sabe o que é com uma string. `30` é um número, `'30'` é uma string e não um valor numérico

Comment: ah sim, entendi então.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa extrair o tempo da string como número inteiro para comparar se ele é menor que 30. Adicione este código dentro do `for`:

```
$tempo = filter_var($resultado['limit-uptime'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if ($tempo < 30) {
    echo 'Tempo menor que 30m';
}
```